# Cachet: Dashboard login outputs 500 error

Tags: linux

So, I'm trying to set this up since yesterday.
As one of the troubleshooting steps I tried to change the directory in cachet-installation/bootstrap/autoload.php to the full path of the directory. After I knew that it doesn’t work I changed it back, but it just doesn’t wanna apply. I tried clearing the cache folder, but still nothing. This is copied from the nginx log: `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/cachet/www/bootstrap/home/cachet/www/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/cachet/www/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 28" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: status.sqlstatement.de, request: "GET /setup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-cachet.sock:", host: "status.sqlstatement.de", referrer: "https://status.sqlstatement.de/setup"`.
I hope somebody here can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled the server and it worked.